# Can't save hashed password to database using bcrypt and bookshelf

Tags: node.js, bcrypt, bookshelf.js

Still quite new to nodejs, so I frequently get tripped up by the whole asynchronous thing. I am attempting to hash a password before storing it in the database, using bcrypt and bookshelf. Pretty straight forward right...

I am calling the save action like so,

```
create(data) {
    this.logger.info(`creating account`);
    return bookshelf.transaction(trx => {
        return new Account().save(data, { method: 'insert', transacting: trx });
    });
}
```

and in the account model, I intercept the save action

```
initialize: function() {
    let _this = this;
    const saltRounds = 10;
    _this.on('creating', function () {
        bcrypt.genSaltSync(saltRounds, function(err, salt) {
            bcrypt.hashSync(_this.get('password'), salt, function (err, hash) {
                if (err) throw err;

                _this.set('password', hash);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Everything i've looked up so far says this should work, but the plain text password is still getting saved into the database instead of the hashed password. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using synchronous functions, but passing them callbacks, which won't get called (and therefore, the password won't be replaced).

Try this:

```
initialize: function() {
  const saltRounds = 10;
  this.on('creating', () => {
    let salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(saltRounds);
    let hash = bcrypt.hashSync(this.get('password'), salt);
    this.set('password', hash);
  });
}
```

Or replacing the synchronous functions with async ones, using promises (which are supported by both `bcrypt` and `bookshelf`):

```
initialize: function() {
  const saltRounds = 10;
  this.on('creating', () => {
    return bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds).then(salt => {
      return bcrypt.hash(this.get('password'), salt);
    }).then(hash => {
      this.set('password', hash);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but i believe the error is because you are using es6 let and not var
then the context of this will defer